# validating the invalid token in expressJWT

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I added a middleware in my API using express JWT. now the problem is when the user sends an invalid token, I got an error 'Unauthorized Error'. what I want is to send and respond to the user when they pass the wrong token.

My ExpressJWT middleware

```
exports.isUserSignedIn = expressJWT({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    userProperty: "auth",
    algorithms: ["HS256"],
})
```

I used this middleware like this in my routes

``
router.get("/get/notifications",[isUserSignedIn], getUserNotification)

Comment: did you try to use the error handling the library recommends? 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt#error-handling

Comment: I saw the code in the document but I am confused about where do I add that code.

Comment: use it right after the last endpoint you define, that example is just a middleware that catches any 401 error, so you can customize the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JWT token verify method to verify the token.

Here is the middleware which can handle empty token as well as an invalid token.

```
exports.checkJWT = (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.headers.authorization) {
        return res.status(403).json({
            message: 'No credentials sent!'
        });
    } else {
        let bearer = req.headers.authorization;
        let token = bearer.split(" ");
        jwt.verify(token[1], process.env.SECRET, function (err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({
                    message: "Invalid token"
                })
            } else {
                next();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can use this middleware in your routes like this.

```
router.get("/get/notifications",[checkJWT], getUserNotification)
```